# using php preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to use PHP preg_math parse a string that looks like:

```
6.15608128 Norwegian kroner
```

I just want the first part (the digits), not the text. I wrote a simple regex like

```
[0-9\.]+
```

that works fine in regex testers, but PHP complains about the '+'. Can anyone help me write this regex so it's valid for the preg_match function? I've tried a ton of different ideas but I'm really not too knowledgeable with regex.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: What do you mean by "PHP complains about the +"? What does it say?

Comment: You don't need to escape the dot when it's inside a character class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The regex works fine](http://www.ideone.com/mRkZN). Are you missing the [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)? The function should be used like this:

```
preg_match('/[0-9\.]+/', $string, $result);
```

(BTW, you don't need to escape the `.` inside the character class. `[0-9.]` is enough.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Kenny, you're right, I was missing the delimiters.

Comment: As you may have guessed I'm messing with the Google currency conversion API. The issue is that they are pretty non-standard with their data, it's not true JSON etc. 

Some of the currency rates have spaces rather than commas or other separators-- eg:

    1 811.5942 Columbian pesos

Is there a way to alter this regex to include that space? Again, in a normal regex you'd just add a space after the dot ([0-9\. ]) but this doesn't work in the PHP.

Thanks again.

Comment: @julio: `[0-9. ]` must work (but that would include the space before 'Columbian' too). If not, try `[0-9.\s]`. If the problem is due to the extra space, try `[\d\s]+\.\d+`.

Comment: you're right, the regex you posted does work. I had an issue due to non-UTF-8 characters.

Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Without having the actual code, here is some code that does work:

```
$string = "6.15608128 Norwegian kroner";
preg_match('#[0-9\.]+#', $string, $matches); 

print_r($matches);

/* Outputs:

     Array
    (
        [0] => 6.15608128
    )
*/
```

The # signs are delimiters. For more information on the regex with php, see [this article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html).

Answer (score 1):

Are you enclosing your pattern in slashes?

`preg_match('/[0-9\.]+/', $string, $matches);`

Comment: It does not *have* to be slashes, just has to be a valid delimiter, as an fyi :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$s = '6.15608128 Norwegian kroner';

preg_match('/[0-9]*\.[0-9]*/', $s, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```